# How to dismiss the keyboard when done editing a text field

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple program where you can type text into a text field, hit an ok button, and a label updates with the text entered.

I want the iPhone keyboard to disappear when I hit the OK button, when I press a large button that is in the background covering the whole view, or when I hit the return button on the keyboard. I have been trying to use the

```
[textField resignFirstResponder]
```

method, but it is not working. The program compiles fine, but when this method is called from any one of those events, it stops, and I get a message saying:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

What am I doing wrong?

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()



    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize txtName;
    @synthesize lblMessage;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)doSomething:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        [txtName resignFirstResponder];

        NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", txtName.text];
        [lblMessage setText:msg];

        //[msg release];
    }

    - (IBAction)makeKeyboardGoAway:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        [txtName resignFirstResponder];
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }

    @end
```

Here is the header file as well:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;

    - (IBAction)doSomething:(UIButton *)sender;
    - (IBAction)makeKeyboardGoAway:(UIButton *)sender;
    @end
```

Well I got it working, but I still don't understand the error message I was getting.
Here is the code that worked for me.

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;

- (IBAction)doSomething;
- (IBAction)makeKeyboardGoAway;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize txtName;
@synthesize lblMessage;

- (IBAction)doSomething
{
    [txtName resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",
                     txtName.text];
    [lblMessage setText:msg];
    //[msg release];
}

- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway
{
    [txtName resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Typically `signal SIGABRT` means you have memory issue somewhere in your code. It looks like in `txtName` you have invalid pointer on `UITextField` object

Comment: Most likely something isn't retained that should be, or, on ARC, you bobbled specifying a pointer attribute somewhere.

Comment: Replace all `txtName` with `self.txtName` and check.

Comment: replacing txtName with self.txtName did not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method when the OK button is clicked.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

This works....if everything lines up with this it might be something else in your code....

...also be sure to have all objects linked correctly (VC to TextField and Button....Button back to VC)...that could also cause the crash

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

   IBOutlet UIButton *button;
   IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
   IBOutlet UILabel *label;
   NSString *string;
}

-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender;


@property (nonatomic, retain)UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UITextField *textfield;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *label;
```

.m

```
@synthesize textfield, button, label;

-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
[textfield resignFirstResponder];
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", textfield.text];
[label setText:string];
}
```

Comment: How does any of this relate to the code posted in the question? That code already calls `resignFirstResponder` on the text field. That is where the problem lies.

Comment: How does it not relate?  No header file was posted....so would it be a bad idea to double check that everything was written as I posted?  This code works with assigning it to any button as well as to the text field itself to release on the return key.  If your code matches this then maybe the SIGABRT is getting thrown from somewhere else and you could at least rule this out.

Comment: Updated to include every part of the posted code.  Maybe he had a different method linked somewhere that was deleted incorrectly....maybe there is something else...but there is no way that this would be throwing an error.

Comment: Can you please explain how your posted answer solves the problem in the question? How does your code solve the SIGABRT runtime error? All you've done is post a random method named `dismiss:`. Also, please explain the first sentence of your answer. I have no idea what it means.

Comment: I didn't try this, but I found how to fix it.